# AWS ecs - All containers gets killed(STOPPED) if one of them exits or killed

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

**Env**

- AWS ecs
- Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build 7392c3b/17.03.1-ce

**Problem**

We've 3 docker containers in our app.

- DB
- DB-seed (DB migration script runner)
- app-server

***DB*** and ***app-server*** gets started, however once the ***DB-seed*** exits(as it should) after running some migration scripts. The rest of the containers die(STOP).

This strange behaviour happens only in AWS ecs and never in my local docker setup.

Moreover, killing any of the containers, stops the other containers in AWS-ECS.

**Our docker compose file**

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: db-image
    hostname: db
    cpu_shares: 50
    mem_limit: 3758096384
    volumes:
     - /data/db:/data/db
    ports:
     - "27017:27017"
  db-seed:
    image:db-seed
    cpu_shares: 10
    mem_limit: 504288000
    links:
    - db
  web:
    image: server-image
    cpu_shares: 50
    mem_limit: 3758096384
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    links:
    - db
```

Is this an issue in AWS ecs or a feature(all or none)?

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the `essential` parameter in your task definition.  Unfortunately I'm not aware of a way to insert this parameter via `docker-compose`, but that's what's causing your behavior in the resultant ECS Task. From the documentation:

> If the essential parameter of a container is marked as `true`, and that container fails or stops for any reason, all other containers that are part of the task are stopped. If the essential parameter of a container is marked as `false`, then its failure does not affect the rest of the containers in a task. If this parameter is omitted, a container is assumed to be essential.

Note that the parameter *defaults* to `true` when it is omitted. Given all of your tasks are missing the parameter, it is expected behavior for them *all* to stop when one of them exits.

More information can be found in the ECS Task Definition Parameters documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_environment

I know this isn't an exact answer, but I hope it helps in determining how to solve your issue.